# Spring jdbc - getJdbcTemplate().queryForList

Tags: spring, jdbc

This below query is returning a single result while executing in sql developoer, but returing empty list while invoking the

```
List failedTxnList =  getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, params);
```

and the value for params are [IM1691, VSIB01, 1/4/2017, 25/4/2017]. Please help me me find the issue here.

```
select a.echeque_no,a.oid,a.echeque_date,d.name im_name,c.name vendor_name,a.corp_ref_no,b.hundi_date,a.echeque_amount,b.reversal_date, 
a.status_description 
from sbicorp_echeque_master a, sbi_gvf_vendor_txn_history b,sbi_gvf_vendor_master c, sbi_gvf_im_master d 
where a.debit_status = 'ERR.' 
  and LTRIM(RTRIM(a.corporate_id))= 'IM1691' 
  and LTRIM(RTRIM(a.businessline_id)) = 'VSIB01'  
  and trunc(a.echeque_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('1/4/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('25/4/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
  and a.corporate_id=d.im_code and a.businessline_id = c.vendor_code
  and b.txn_type= 'Original Debit' 
  and a.echeque_no = b.reference_no 
  and substr(a.echeque_no,0,2) in ('CE','CR','CN','CZ') 
order by echeque_date desc -- CE01573281
```

Comment: this is the result of my query :

Comment: sorry not able to post the result , but the result has 10 column and one row

Comment: ECHEQUE_NO    OID         ECHEQUE_DATE  IM_NAME       VENDOR_NAME    CORP_REF_NO   HUNDI_DATE       ECHEQUE_AMOUNT     REVERSAL_DATE   STATUS_DESCRIPTION

Comment: CE01573281    5605816732 02-APR-17     sibinlafim      VENSIB            011234566   02-OCT-16          1300            03-OCT-16       (null)

Comment: above is the query result , is the null for the last column value causes any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is

```
trunc(a.echeque_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('1/4/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('25/4/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Try to change date string to reflect dequired format

```
TO_DATE ('01/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('25/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

The List that you are fetching must be of some type and it must implement rowMapper. The rowMapper tells spring which column maps to which object.

An Example is mentioned below.
Circle Model Class: The fields are the columns in database.

```
public class Circle {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Circle(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Circle(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Define a row Mapper for spring to map database columns to Circle objects

```
public static final class CircleMapper implements RowMapper<Circle> {
        public Circle mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int arg1) throws SQLException {
            return new Circle(resultSet.getInt("id"),resultSet.getString("name"));  

        }   
    }
```

And in Your Service class call the object.

```
Circle circle = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * from circle where id = ?", new Object [] {id}, new CircleMapper());
```

For your case, create a model class with database columns.
Create a mapper class, and then execute.